# An error occurred while installing rdiscount (2.2.0.1) and Bundler cannot continue on Mac OS and Ruby 2.7.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rdiscount

**Problem:**

I have tried to do a `gem install rdiscount -v '2.2.0.1'` and get an error.

**Solution:**

I have tried below command to get this to work

`gem install rdiscount:2.2.0.1 -- --with-cflags="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration"`

**Error looks like**

```html
Fetching rdiscount 2.2.0.1
Installing rdiscount 2.2.0.1 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/kgarigipati/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rdiscount-2.2.0.1/ext
/Users/kgarigipati/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/bin/ruby -I /Users/kgarigipati/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0 -r ./siteconf20201104-70970-w4fetk.rb extconf.rb
checking for random()... yes
checking for srandom()... yes
checking for rand()... yes
checking for srand()... yes
creating Makefile

current directory: /Users/kgarigipati/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rdiscount-2.2.0.1/ext
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /Users/kgarigipati/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rdiscount-2.2.0.1/ext
make "DESTDIR="
compiling Csio.c
compiling amalloc.c
amalloc.c:23:1: warning: function 'die' could be declared with attribute 'noreturn' [-Wmissing-noreturn]
{
^
amalloc.c:39:14: warning: using the result of an assignment as a condition without parentheses [-Wparentheses]
    if ( ret = calloc(count + sizeof(struct alist) + sizeof(int), size) ) {
         ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
amalloc.c:39:14: note: place parentheses around the assignment to silence this warning
    if ( ret = calloc(count + sizeof(struct alist) + sizeof(int), size) ) {
             ^
         (                                                             )
amalloc.c:39:14: note: use '==' to turn this assignment into an equality comparison
    if ( ret = calloc(count + sizeof(struct alist) + sizeof(int), size) ) {
             ^
             ==
amalloc.c:76:10: warning: passing 'const char [46]' to parameter of type 'char *' discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
            die("goddam: corrupted memory block %d in free()!\n", p2->index);
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
amalloc.c:22:11: note: passing argument to parameter 'msg' here
die(char *msg, int index)
          ^
amalloc.c:95:10: warning: passing 'const char [49]' to parameter of type 'char *' discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
            die("goddam: corrupted memory block %d in realloc()!\n", p2->index);
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
amalloc.c:22:11: note: passing argument to parameter 'msg' here
die(char *msg, int index)
          ^
4 warnings generated.
compiling basename.c
compiling css.c
css.c:81:28: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
    written = (size > 0) ? fwrite(res,1,size,f) : 0;
            ~              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
compiling docheader.c
compiling dumptree.c
dumptree.c:23:29: warning: returning 'const char [11]' from a function with result type 'char *' discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
    case WHITESPACE: return "whitespace";
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~
dumptree.c:24:29: warning: returning 'const char [5]' from a function with result type 'char *' discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
    case CODE      : return "code";
                            ^~~~~~
dumptree.c:25:29: warning: returning 'const char [6]' from a function with result type 'char *' discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
    case QUOTE     : return "quote";
                            ^~~~~~~
dumptree.c:26:29: warning: returning 'const char [7]' from a function with result type 'char *' discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
    case MARKUP    : return "markup";
                            ^~~~~~~~
dumptree.c:27:29: warning: returning 'const char [5]' from a function with result type 'char *' discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
    case HTML      : return "html";
                            ^~~~~~
dumptree.c:28:29: warning: returning 'const char [3]' from a function with result type 'char *' discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
    case DL        : return "dl";
                            ^~~~
dumptree.c:29:29: warning: returning 'const char [3]' from a function with result type 'char *' discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
    case UL        : return "ul";
                            ^~~~
dumptree.c:30:29: warning: returning 'const char [3]' from a function with result type 'char *' discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
    case OL        : return "ol";
                            ^~~~
dumptree.c:31:29: warning: returning 'const char [5]' from a function with result type 'char *' discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
    case LISTITEM  : return "item";
                            ^~~~~~
dumptree.c:32:29: warning: returning 'const char [7]' from a function with result type 'char *' discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
    case HDR       : return "header";
                            ^~~~~~~~
dumptree.c:33:29: warning: returning 'const char [3]' from a function with result type 'char *' discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
    case HR        : return "hr";
                            ^~~~
dumptree.c:34:29: warning: returning 'const char [6]' from a function with result type 'char *' discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
    case TABLE     : return "table";
                            ^~~~~~~
dumptree.c:35:29: warning: returning 'const char [7]' from a function with result type 'char *' discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
    case SOURCE    : return "source";
                            ^~~~~~~~
dumptree.c:36:29: warning: returning 'const char [6]' from a function with result type 'char *' discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
    case STYLE     : return "style";
                            ^~~~~~~
dumptree.c:37:29: warning: returning 'const char [14]' from a function with result type 'char *' discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
    default        : return "mystery node!";
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
dumptree.c:104:33: warning: initializing 'char *' with an expression of type 'const char [2]' discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
    static char *Begin[] = { 0, "P", "center" };
                                ^~~
dumptree.c:104:38: warning: initializing 'char *' with an expression of type 'const char [7]' discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
    static char *Begin[] = { 0, "P", "center" };
                                     ^~~~~~~~
17 warnings generated.
compiling emmatch.c
emmatch.c:113:20: warning: using the result of an assignment as a condition without parentheses [-Wparentheses]
    case 2: if ( e = empair(f,first,last,match=2) )
                 ~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
emmatch.c:113:20: note: place parentheses around the assignment to silence this warning
    case 2: if ( e = empair(f,first,last,match=2) )
                   ^
                 (                               )
emmatch.c:113:20: note: use '==' to turn this assignment into an equality comparison
    case 2: if ( e = empair(f,first,last,match=2) )
                   ^
                   ==
1 warning generated.
compiling flags.c
flags.c:10:27: warning: initializing 'char *' with an expression of type 'const char [7]' discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
    { MKD_NOLINKS,        "!LINKS" },
 
                          
################### Here continues bunch of warnings (log is too big to include) ###############


  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
rdiscount.c:36:7: warning: initializing 'char *' with an expression of type 'const char [17]' discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
    { "no_strikethrough", MKD_NOSTRIKETHROUGH },
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
rdiscount.c:53:17: error: implicit declaration of function 'rb_rdiscount__get_flags' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    int flags = rb_rdiscount__get_flags(self);
                ^
rdiscount.c:66:48: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
    MMIOT *doc = mkd_string(RSTRING_PTR(text), RSTRING_LEN(text), flags);
                 ~~~~~~~~~~                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/kgarigipati/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:1007:6: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_LEN'
     RSTRING_EMBED_LEN(str) : \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/kgarigipati/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:1003:6: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_EMBED_LEN'
     (long)((RBASIC(str)->flags >> RSTRING_EMBED_LEN_SHIFT) & \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
rdiscount.c:66:48: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
    MMIOT *doc = mkd_string(RSTRING_PTR(text), RSTRING_LEN(text), flags);
                 ~~~~~~~~~~                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/kgarigipati/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:1008:28: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_LEN'
     RSTRING(str)->as.heap.len)
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
rdiscount.c:96:17: error: implicit declaration of function 'rb_rdiscount__get_flags' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    int flags = rb_rdiscount__get_flags(self);
                ^
rdiscount.c:105:48: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
    MMIOT *doc = mkd_string(RSTRING_PTR(text), RSTRING_LEN(text), flags);
                 ~~~~~~~~~~                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/kgarigipati/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:1007:6: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_LEN'
     RSTRING_EMBED_LEN(str) : \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/kgarigipati/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:1003:6: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_EMBED_LEN'
     (long)((RBASIC(str)->flags >> RSTRING_EMBED_LEN_SHIFT) & \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
rdiscount.c:105:48: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
    MMIOT *doc = mkd_string(RSTRING_PTR(text), RSTRING_LEN(text), flags);
                 ~~~~~~~~~~                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/kgarigipati/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:1008:28: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_LEN'
     RSTRING(str)->as.heap.len)
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
16 warnings and 2 errors generated.
make: *** [rdiscount.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/kgarigipati/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rdiscount-2.2.0.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/kgarigipati/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-19/2.7.0/rdiscount-2.2.0.1/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing rdiscount (2.2.0.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rdiscount -v '2.2.0.1'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  rdiscount
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're building on macOS Big Sur then you'll need to upgrade to RDiscount 2.2.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

in big Sur, I encountered a similar problem when installing `rb-appscript`:
`sudo gem install rb-appscript`

```
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rb-appscript:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rb-appscript-0.6.1
/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby -I /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0 -r ./siteconf20201125-30706-1azyih7.rb extconf.rb --with-cflags\=-Wno-error\=implicit-function-declaration
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.7.2/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
extconf.rb:44:in `<main>': uninitialized constant Config (NameError)
Did you mean?  RbConfig
               CONFIG

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rb-appscript-0.6.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-19/2.7.0/rb-appscript-0.6.1/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem on my Ubuntu. It just solved after;

```
sudo apt install ruby-rubygems
```